# Click event is not working when Chrome starts mobile phone simulation

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I wrote a test script, using the chrome browser to simulate the phone mode. Text input is no problem, but the click event does not respond. An error message appears:

> Click timed out after 60 seconds.

I used the following NuGet packages:

> Selenium.Support 3.8.0
>   Selenium.WebDriver 3.8.0
>   Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver 2.34.0

Below is my code:

```
    ChromeOptions cos = new ChromeOptions();
    string userAgent ="Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75 Mobile/14E5239e Safari/602.1";
    //string userAgent = "Linux; Android 4.1.1; GT-N7100 Build/JRO03C) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/35.0.1916.138 Mobile Safari/537.36 T7/6.3";
    cos.EnableMobileEmulation(new ChromeMobileEmulationDeviceSettings() { Width = 375, Height = 667, UserAgent = userAgent , EnableTouchEvents=true, PixelRatio=3.0 });
    //cos.EnableMobileEmulation(new ChromeMobileEmulationDeviceSettings() { Width = 320, Height = 540, UserAgent = userAgent, EnableTouchEvents = true, PixelRatio = 3.0 });

    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cos);
    driver.Manage().Window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(395, 810);//

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://m.baidu.com/");

    Console.WriteLine("Page Loaded");

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

    try
    {
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("index-kw")));
        var item = driver.FindElement(By.Id("index-kw"));
        item.SendKeys("selenium c#");
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("text enter");
    try
    {
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("index-bn")));
        var item = driver.FindElement(By.Id("index-bn"));
        item.Click();
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("finished");

    Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues before with Click() that I assumed were due to whatever javascript executes on the button click conflicting with whatever Click() tries to do.

I've resolved them using item.SendKeys(Keys.Enter) instead. Might be worth a shot.

Comment: 3 years later, I'm getting timeout on `getScreenshot` and then the `Quit()` doesn't seem to get called, leaving the `chromedriver` process running. It happens on a Linux (Ubuntu 20.04). Also, only when using `ChromeMobileEmulationDeviceSettings`, etc, although not immediately as far as I can tell - I have 27 different configurations, the first 4 or so (each run a different number but always around 4) pass then it starts to timeout. I run many other `WebDriver` commands including `ExecuteScript` before that one and they all pass. When not in Mobile Emulation mode everything works fine.